# Can we prove $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+n}=1$ using Theorem 1 from Ch. 20 of Spivak's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

In Spivak's *Calculus* there is the following theorem (I am paraphrasing)

> **Ch. 22, Theorem 1** If a function $f$ is defined in an open interval containing $c$ except perhaps at $c$, with $$\lim\limits_{x\to
> > c}f(x)=l\tag{1}$$ then
>
> For every sequence ${a_n}$ such that
>
> - each $a_n$ is in the domain of $f$
> - each $a_n\neq 0$
> - $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=c$
>
> the sequence $f(a_n)$ satisfies
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=l\tag{2}$$
>
> Conversely, if for every sequence $a_n$ satisfying the three
> conditions above there is a sequence $f(a_n)$ satisfying $(2)$, then
> $(1)$ is true.

Can apply this theorem directly to prove that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+n}=1$$

?

Here is the proposed argument

$$\sqrt[n]{n^2+n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log{(n^2+n)}}$$

$$a_n=\frac{\log{(n^2+n)}}{n}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$$

Let $f(x)=e^x$.

Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)=1$.

Since each $a_n$ is in the domain of $f$, which is all numbers, each $a_n\neq 0$ and $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$$, we can infer that the sequence $f(a_n)$ satisfies

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(a_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2+n}=1$$

Comment: Sure. What are your worries?

Comment: Just want to confirm so I can be sure because the solution manual has a different solution based on the relationship $\sqrt[n]{n^2}<\sqrt[n]{n^2+n}<\sqrt[n]{2n^2}=\sqrt[n]{2}\sqrt[n]{n^2}$, and the fact that we computed the limits as $n\to\infty$ of $\sqrt[n]{n^2}$ and $\sqrt[n]{2}$ previously (they both equal $1$).

Comment: You surely can, but I guess maybe the question was originally expecting readers to solve it via the properties of sequences themselves instead of applying some theorem related to continuous functions.

Comment: In your proof your not (only) using the theorem you mention but the fact that $\exp$ is a continuous function

Comment: Your solution and the books solution are basically doing the same thing.  Your solution is doing $\log(n^2 + n)/n < \log(2n^2)/n = (\log(2) + 1/2 ~ \log(n)) / n$ and $\log(n)/n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of theorems then:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{n^2 + n} &= e^{\ln(n^2 + n)/n} = 1 + \frac{\ln(n^2 + n)}{n} + \frac{\ln^{2}(n^2 + n)}{2 \, n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\ln^3(n)}{n^3} \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{2 \, \ln(n)}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
An alternate view is:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{n^2 + n} &= e^{\ln(n^2 + n)/n} = e^{\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)/n} \times e^{2 \, \ln n/n} \\
&= e^{\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)/n} \, \left( 1 + \frac{2 \, \ln n}{n} + \frac{2^2 \, \ln^2 n}{2 \, n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln^3 n}{n^3}\right) \right)
\end{align}
Since both $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ tend to zero as $n \to \infty$ then $\text{exp}\left( \frac{1}{n} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. This leaves
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2 + n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{2 \, \ln n}{n} + \frac{2^2 \, \ln^2 n}{2 \, n^2} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln^3 n}{n^3}\right) \right). $$

Since $ \ln n < n$ then $\frac{\ln n}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2 + n} = 1.$$

Otherwise the problem proposer has provided a solution by use of a theorem which produces the same desired result.

Comment: A few questions on the asymptotic notation. First of all, that symbol you are using is little-o, right? On the first line, shouldn't it be $o(\frac{\ln^4{n}}{n^4})$? After all the next term in the Taylor polynomial would be $\frac{\ln^3{(n^2+n)}}{3!n^3}$, and this is not, as far as I can tell, $o(\frac{\ln^3{n}}{n^3})$.

Comment: @evianpring    yes, "order of" notation can be called little-o, or big-o, but all meaning roughly the same. The $O(x^m)$ meaning gives the next term in the expansion, not the next next term. In this case the terms of $\ln(n^2+n) = 2 \, \ln n + \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ have been reduced by ignoring the $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ terms since these are zero when $n \to \infty$. This leaves terms of $\ln(n)/n$.

Comment: I only recently learned about these notations. As I learned it, Big-O means "something that is, in absolute value, at most a constant multiple of the absolute value of". So if we say $g(n)=O(\frac{\ln^3(n)}{n^3})$ then it means that $|g(n)|\leq A|\frac{\ln^3(n)}{n^3}|$, for some constant $A$ that doesn't depend on $n$. But in your example, the next term in the Taylor polynomial is $\frac{\ln^3{(n^2+n)}}{n^33!}$. If we try to find a constant that makes this equal to $\frac{\ln^3(n)}{n^3}$ we obtain the expression $\frac{\log{(n^2+n)}}{\log{(n^3)}}$, which depends on $n$.

Comment: Rather than elaborate further, I think this will merit another question so that I may organize my reasoning better.